# Amazon SageMaker BlazingText

Tags: amazon-web-services, nlp, word2vec, gensim, amazon-sagemaker

I am working on a word embedding project. I am using Amazon SageMaker for this purpose. The BlazingText algorithm in the Amazon SageMaker produced fast result than the other options. But I don't see any facility to get the prediction model or the weights. The output consists only the vectors file from which I cannot generate the model.
Is there any way by which I can get the model with the vector file? I need this to predict new words. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by “predict new words”? Word embedding is creating embedding to words in your “vocabulary“ and not new words. You can use stemming or hashing to handle out-of-vocabulary words, but not the embedding model.

Comment: I am building a skip-gram based embedding model. usually skip-gram model outputs the context for a given word. I am doing this for a research and for the evaluations I want to get the context output. I am trying to solve polysemy words. So only the word embedding results are not enough. The requirement I have is the basic skip-gram model where I can get the context as output for a word.

Comment: How to get bigrams and trigrams trained with Amazon BlazingText?

Answer (score 0):

You can reproduce similar results like, most_similar by uploading the vector.txt/bin file using KeyedVectors api.

Here is an example:

```
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
word_vectors = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('vectors.txt', binary=False) 
word_vectors = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('vectors.bin', binary=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is (if I understand you correctly) how to create an endpoint in order to get the vectors for new words.
look up the [example](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/master/introduction_to_amazon_algorithms/blazingtext_word2vec_text8) for blazingtext. Down at the bottom, they show how to create such endpoint.

If you want to predict new words, that are not known to the model, use [subwords](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/introduction_to_amazon_algorithms/blazingtext_word2vec_subwords_text8/blazingtext_word2vec_subwords_text8.ipynb).

Answer (score -1):

BlazingText models can generate vectors for new words if you enable the subword embeddings learning by setting the "subwords" parameter to True while training.
Once the training job is complete, you will need to create a SageMaker endpoint and deploy the model. You can send POST requests to this endpoint for retrieving the word vectors, as demonstrated in the "Hosting / Inference" section of [this notebook](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/introduction_to_amazon_algorithms/blazingtext_word2vec_subwords_text8/blazingtext_word2vec_subwords_text8.ipynb):

> ```
> bt_endpoint = bt_model.deploy(initial_instance_count = 1,instance_type = 'ml.m4.xlarge')
> words = ["awesome", "awweeesome"]
> payload = {"instances" : words}
> response = bt_endpoint.predict(json.dumps(payload))
> vecs = json.loads(response)
> ```

For more details about this feature, you can also refer to [this blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/enhanced-text-classification-and-word-vectors-using-amazon-sagemaker-blazingtext/) post.